# jwplayer code issue

Tags: php, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have this code

```
<?php
srand((float) microtime() * 1971);
$input = array("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2G5oim2mYM", "http://www.cinedoanula.com/TESTES/wwwcinedoanulacom.mp4", "http://www.cinedoanula.com/TESTES/wwwcinedoanulacom.mp4");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
$mixupa = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $mixupa
?>

<body>
<div id="myplayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("myplayer").setup({file: '<?php $mixupa ?>',
skin: "vapor",
autostart: "false",width: "100%", height: "85%"});</script>
</div></body></html>
```

What I'm doing wrong. I can't make it work. The first part (php) is correctly but I can't make php run in file source

I'm tried n JWP 6 and 7

Comment: What errors (*if any*) are you getting?

Comment: the file doesn't run. It supposed to run one of the youtube links above

Comment: `<?php $mixupa ?>` should be `<?php echo $mixupa; ?>`

Comment: And that ^^^^^^ is how it'll work again

Comment: not for me, this block the jwplayer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues here:

1. As suggested, **<?php $mixupa ?>** should be **<?php echo($mixupa);
   ?>**
2. **$mixupa** should not end with a newline character **.'\n'**. You should remove this.
3. Using **height: "85%"** will only work if you have explicitly defined a height for the parent container - in this case the BODY. You should remove this setting or add the relevant CSS to assign a height to the BODY.
4. In JW6 you need a **Pro edition** (or greater) licence key to use a pre-built skin (**skin: "vapor"**) in this way. If you don't have a Pro licence key you should remove this setting.
5. In JW7 you need to provide a valid licence key regardless of which edition you are using. If you are using JW7 with a valid key, then you can leave the **skin: "vapor"** setting.

Here's an example of your code/setup working with these issues resolved: http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/debug/anulador/

Comment: jherrieven, thanks a lot, you got it!!!!! The problem was .'\n'. That was enough to achieve what I want. Thanks a lot man. You are great.